# Como puedo filtrar los siguientes items en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Cordial saludo

La presente es para manifestar una duda técnica pequeña, tengo el siguiente array, pero quiero utilizar filter para sacar todo el objeto quitando el indice 0 que comienza, cada vez que tratato de utilizar el elemento tengo que pasar ese indice, como hago para sacarlo del objeto o filtrarlo para que me permita acceder a esos elementos sin pasar ese indice.

```
0: [
    {
        "name": {
            "common": "Colombia",
            "official": "Republic of Colombia",
            "nativeName": {
                "spa": {
                    "official": "República de Colombia",
                    "common": "Colombia"
                }
            }
        }
]
```

Comment: asígnalo a una nueva variable... `const elemento = array[0]`, luego el acceso es con la variable `elemento`

Comment: Gracias por la solución también me funciono pero utilice shift al final.

Comment: Sólo recuerda que `.shift()` cambia el tamaño del arreglo. Tal vez en este momento no te importe, pero es algo para tener en cuenta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agregamos el arreglo dentro de una variable.

```
var lista = [
        {
            "name": {
                "common": "Colombia",
                "official": "Republic of Colombia",
                "nativeName": {
                    "spa": {
                        "official": "República de Colombia",
                        "common": "Colombia"
                    }
                }
            }
    ];
```

Utilizamos la función **shift** devuelve el primer elemento del arreglo y este es asignado a la variable **primerElemento**.

```
var primerElemento = lista.shift();
```

Desde ahora para acceder a los datos es desde la variable **primerElemento**

Comment: Esta solución me funciono para lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias por compartir la solución

Comment: Te voté negativamente porque las respuestas de sólo código, sin explicación de cómo y por qué resuelven el problema de OP. Por favor añade una explicación y con gusto remuevo el voto negativo

Comment: Dale, puedes marcar como respuesta correcta